# one node cassanda overload when starting spark task

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

I have 20 nodes cluster with cassandra 2.1.11, standalone spark 1.5 and cassandra-connector 2.10:1.5. When i run spark tasks they completed successfully, but at first momemnt of starting task one of the nodes is very overloaded (os load about 90% and cassandra heap usage 100% ) otherwise another nodes stays 10% usage cpu and 20% heap usege. After few seconds heap comes normally (3-4Gib) but in some cases i have OutOfMemory (by heap) or/and GC long pauses. In all tests single overloaded node is the same.

All nodes have the same cassandra parameters and xmx=19Gib.

How to solve single cassandra node overload?

Comment: Are you running the spark job in local mode? can you edit your question and show us how is the spark job submitted?

Comment: Is this the node you execute your job on? Can you show us code of your job, maybe we could optimize it...

Comment: Yes, spark deployed in local mode. I have java application that create spark context and then create RDD from cassandra table with filtering and mapping. Spark-master  is located on the another node and java-application is also located on the another node.